# Custom Marker Icon Image Url GoogleMap Compose Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-jetpack-compose, customization, google-app-maker

GoogleMap composes support maker icons but does not help get from Url, I hope some coding helps customer properties Icons image easy more. But If you have a solution good more, please comment here

*Code in GoogleMap compose*

```
val bitmapState = remember {
                mutableStateOf<BitmapDescriptor?>(null)
            }
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = locationFocus.value.imageUrl) {
                getBitmapFromURL(locationFocus.value.imageUrl)?.let { bm ->
                    getResizedBitmap(bm, 150, 150)?.let {
                        getRoundedCornerBitmap(it)?.let {
                            bitmapState.value =
                                BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(it)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Marker(
                state = MarkerState(position = cameraPositionState.position.target),
                title = locationFocus.value.name,
                snippet = locationFocus.value.address,
                icon = bitmapState.value,
            )
        }

//Get Bitmap from Url
suspend fun getBitmapFromURL(imgUrl: String?): Bitmap? =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val url = URL(imgUrl)
            val connection: HttpURLConnection =
                url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            connection.doInput = true
            connection.connect()
            val input: InputStream = connection.inputStream
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // Log exception
            null
        }
    }
//Resize Image Bitmap
fun getResizedBitmap(bm: Bitmap, newWidth: Int, newHeight: Int): Bitmap? {
    ...
    bm.recycle()
    return resizedBitmap
}

//Border Bitmap
fun getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap? {
   ...
    return output
}
```

> If you have another code simple please comment. Good job

Answer (score -1):

Image result marker icon google map compose.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the source codes just for the marker?

Comment: Do you want the source code to make RoundedCorner? Because Marker is a widget available by GoogleMap this code only loads Icon bitmap custom.

Comment: I would be very happy if I could reach all of them.

Comment: fun getResizedBitmap(bm: Bitmap, newWidth: Int, newHeight: Int): Bitmap? {
    val width = bm.width
    val height = bm.height
    val scaleWidth = newWidth.toFloat() / width
    val scaleHeight = newHeight.toFloat() / height
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    val matrix = Matrix()
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)

    // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
    val resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false)
    bm.recycle()
    return resizedBitmap
}

Comment: fun getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap? {
    val w=bitmap.width
    val h=bitmap.height
    val radius = (h / 2).coerceAtMost(w / 2)
    val output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w + 16, h + 16, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val paint = Paint()
    paint.isAntiAlias = true
    val canvas = Canvas(output)
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
    paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
    canvas.drawCircle((w / 2 + 8).toFloat(), (h / 2 + 8).toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), paint)
 //continue

Comment: paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 4f, 4f, paint)
    paint.xfermode = null
    paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    paint.color =  Color.argb(55f,139f,195f,74f)
    paint.strokeWidth = 10f
    canvas.drawCircle((w / 2 + 8).toFloat(), (h / 2 + 8).toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), paint)
    return output
}

Comment: @VahitKeskin this code custom in here